# Block Users from Enabling a Partner Account if Record Type is not Customer

Tags: validation, account, partner

Trying to create a validation to check if a partner account enabled is of any other record type than a specific value.

Validation:

```
AND(
 OR(
 RecordType.Name <> 'Legal Entity' ,
 RecordType.Name <> 'Partner' ,
 RecordType.Name <> 'Prospect'
 ),
 ISCHANGED(IsPartner)
)
```

Error while checking Syntax:
Error: Field IsPartner does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: for what object you r creating the validation rule ??

Comment: You may need to do it in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard limitation of Salesforce that you cannot use `IsPartner` field of `Account` in custom Formula.

However already an [**Idea**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kluZAAQ) has been raised with Salesforce.